# Incompatible types when initialising pointer to structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following in my code, `RDMPacket` is a struct defined in an included header file. The first 3 buffer pointers (DMX buffers) work fine but the second 3 (the RDM buffers) do not. Am I doing something wrong? How else could I refer to a set of structs with pointers?

```
uint8_t dmxRxBufA[NumberOfChannels];
uint8_t dmxRxBufB[NumberOfChannels];
uint8_t dmxRxBufC[NumberOfChannels];

uint8_t *pDMXWriteBuf = dmxRxBufA;
uint8_t *pDMXSpareBuf = dmxRxBufB;
uint8_t *pDMXReadBuf  = dmxRxBufC;

RDMPacket rdmRxBufA;
RDMPacket rdmRxBufB;
RDMPacket rdmRxBufC;

RDMPacket *pRDMWriteBuf = rdmRxBufA;
RDMPacket *pRDMSpareBuf = rdmRxBufB;
RDMPacket *pRDMReadBuf  = rdmRxBufC;

uart.c:90:27: error: incompatible types when initializing type 'struct RDMPacket *' using type 'RDMPacket'
uart.c:91:27: error: incompatible types when initializing type 'struct RDMPacket *' using type 'RDMPacket'
uart.c:92:26: error: incompatible types when initializing type 'struct RDMPacket *' using type 'RDMPacket'
```

Comment: You are assigning type `struct RDMPacket` to type `struct* RDMPacket`. Assign the pointer the ADDRESS of the struct instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three are arrays of `uint8_t`. It means that dmxRxBuf is a pointer to the first element, thus, a `uint8_t*` The others are just `RDMPacket`. If you want to pass their address, you could use this :

```
RDMPacket *pRDMWriteBuf = &rdmRxBufA;
RDMPacket *pRDMSpareBuf = &rdmRxBufB;
RDMPacket *pRDMReadBuf  = &rdmRxBufC;
```

Or create arrays of `RDMPacket`, as you did for uint8_t

```
RDMPacket rdmRxBufA[];
RDMPacket rdmRxBufB[];
RDMPacket rdmRxBufC[];
```

Answer (score 1):

You must put addresses to pointers. Use `&` operator to get address:

```
RDMPacket *pRDMWriteBuf = &rdmRxBufA;
RDMPacket *pRDMSpareBuf = &rdmRxBufB;
RDMPacket *pRDMReadBuf  = &rdmRxBufC;
```

---

It is a bit unclear from question, but if you actually want arrays of structs, same way you have arrays of `unit8_t`, then just make them arrays of structs:

```
RDMPacket rdmRxBufA[NumberOfChannels];
RDMPacket rdmRxBufB[NumberOfChannels];
RDMPacket rdmRxBufC[NumberOfChannels];
```

Now `rdmRxBufA` and so on give pointer the first element of the array, and you can again assign to pointers directly.

---

You seem to be confused about different semantics of arrays and structs, if you thought you didn't need the `&` operator.

With arrays like `int a[]`, `a` alone gives pointer to the first element of the array, `&(a[0])`.
 (A side note: `&a` also returns pointer with same value, but to a different type, pointer to the whole array, and is very rarely correct).

However, structs are more "normal" types. You can use them as values, such as pass them as arguments and assign them to other variables of same type, so you could say for example `rdmRxBufA = rdmRxBufB;` and that is valid assignment. If you want the address, you need the `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array without index let's the array decay to a pointer to it's 1st element.

This

```
uint8_t * pDMXWriteBuf = dmxRxBufA;
```

is the same as

```
uint8_t * pDMXWriteBuf = &dmxRxBufA[0];
```

The `struct`s aren't arrays, so they won't decay. Use `&`, the `Address Of`-operator instead.

```
RDMPacket * pRDMWriteBuf = &rdmRxBufA;
```